# Algorithm of tree partition

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am looking for algorithm which allows to do following:

Let $T$ is some tree, where each vertex $V_i$ has its  cost $c_i$. I am looking for algorithm which allows to split $T$ (by removing two edges) to three connected components $S_i$ with equal sum of costs of vertices

Comment: You can always try to consider all pairs of edges to remove. Then once you removes two, run a DFS/BFS to check if you indeed have 3 distincts connected component and, while doing the DFS, sum the costs of the vertices.
I'm not saying it's a clever solution but it should still be polynomial (Like $O(|V|^3)$ I would guess).

Comment: @Zubzub, I agree, this kind of brute force will work. Maybe it is good place to optimize algorithm

Comment: Note that this is not always possible to do. Consider a star $S_n$ with leaf costs $c_i=1$ and central node cost $c_i>1$.

Comment: What do you want to do if you can't decompose the tree in that way? For example the root having cost $1$ and it's sole two childs has cost $2$ and $3$? What if the tree only have two or fewer nodes?

Comment: @SantanaAfton, Yes, of cource, another simple observation is that summary weight should be divided by 3. I think that in such case is enough just to say that solution does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't something like this base algorithm work?

1. Collect all leafs
2. For all nodes connected with a leaf, create a new leaf with the sum of the leafs and the node.
3. Once it exceeds 1/3 of the total, cut it off as a tree.

There will be special cases, and you may need to throw in some tree balancing when there are large differences in weights of the leafs/nodes.

Comment: How does your algorithm work with "deep" trees?

Comment: +1 Had the same idea, but too late :) Iterate over leaves. If a leaf's value is less than 1/3 of the total sum, it can't be cut off, so incorporate it into its neighbour. If the resulting node is more than 1/3 of the total, the solution does not exist → exit with failure status. Repeat until failure or until there are 2 leaves each 1/3 of total; in the latter case cut the two, aglutinate the rest → success.

Comment: @LmTinyToon I guess, by 'deep tree' you mean a branch with many nodes and the single leaf at the end, right? Then, after replacing the leaf and its neighbor with a new node, the new node becomes a new leaf, so you can iterate the process on it.

Answer (score 2):

What I would have done is to do a DFS of the tree and for each node calculate the sum of the cost of the node and it's descendents. One stores the path to the nodes along with this values and then sorts by value.

Then one can identify which nodes that carry about a third of the cost and spawn that one off. Then for the second to be spawned of you need to take into account whether the first node is a descendent or not (which is where the stored path would be used). If the first is a descendent the second would have to carry about two-third of the cost, otherwise it would have to carry one-third (you have to look for this second at two places in the sorted list).

This should have $O(N\log N)$ time complexity and $O(N)$ space. If the tree is very deep you would need to use a hash-table representation of the path or the depth would have an impact on the complexity. Also there would be some cost if there's many candidates for the first and second nodes that have to be considered (if it's critical that the solution is optimal).

To take an example, consider the sexp `(1 (2 (3 (4 5) 6) 7 8 (9 (10 11) 12)))` (the parenthesis following a number contains it's children, the tree is that from [wikipedia on DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)). Doing the DFS search (which is right to left for a sexp) gives a table of costs:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{path} & \text{cost}\\
\hline
1/2/3/4 & 4\\
1/2/3/5 & 5\\
1/2/3   & 12\\
1/2/6   & 6 \\
1/2     & 20 \\
1/7     & 7 \\
1/8/9/10 & 10 \\
1/8/9/11 & 11 \\
1/8/9    & 30 \\
1/8/12   & 12 \\
1/8      & 50 \\
1        & 78
\end{matrix}$$

Then you sort by cost:$$\begin{matrix}
\text{path} & \text{cost}\\
\hline
1/2/3/4 & 4\\
1/2/3/5 & 5\\
1/2/6   & 6 \\
1/7     & 7 \\
1/8/9/10 & 10 \\
1/8/9/11 & 11 \\
1/2/3   & 12\\
1/8/12   & 12 \\
1/2     & 20 \\
1/8/9    & 30 \\
1/8      & 50 \\
1        & 78 \\
\end{matrix}$$

Now you're looking for a cost of $78/3 = 26$, the best match is $1/2$ and the second best is $1/8/9$. Now you see that they and their descendents are disjoint so they're allowed. We should also for the second consider matches near $2\times78/3=52$, for example $1/8$ we see on the path that the node $1/8/9$ and it's descendant is subtree of $1/8$ and it's descendants (which is the case that would include $1/8$. So now we have two candidates, using the subtrees rooted by $1/8/9$ (of cost $30$) and $1/2$ (of cost $20$) and the remainder (of cost $28 = 70-30-20$). The other candidate is the subtree rooted by $1/8/9$ (of cost $30$) and $1/8$ (of cost $20=50-30$) and finally the remainder (of cost $28 = 78-50$). This last step differs a bit depending how you value the goodness of the solution, here I'd say they're equally good, you divide both with costs $20+28+30$.

A comment was that the algorithm seem to require a directed tree, but that can be created selecting a root node. As an example if we use the same (undirected) tree and choose $4$ as the root instead we get the table:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{path} & \text{cost}\\
\hline
4/3/2/1/8/12   & 12 \\
4/3/2/1/8/9/11 & 11 \\
4/3/2/1/8/9/10 & 10 \\
4/3/2/1/8/9    & 30 \\
4/3/2/1/8      & 50 \\
4/3/2/1/7      & 7 \\
4/3/2/1        & 58 \\
4/3/2/6        & 6 \\
4/3/2          & 66 \\
4/3/5          & 5 \\
4/3            & 74 \\
4              & 78 \\
\end{matrix}$$

You see here for example that the nearest to $26$ is $4/3/2/1/8/9$ with cost $30$. And in looking near $52$ we see $4/3/2/1/8$ with cost $50$ and $4/3/2/1$ with cost $58$, both of these are antecedents of the first so they are allowed. These exactly corresponds to the solution in the first case (ie you cut between $8$ and $9$ in combination with $1$ and $2$ or $1$ and $8$).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your question (by english is bad). At the moment, I have understood that you suggest to precompute sum of nodes and its children. Next step is vague for me

Comment: My algorithm is a bit sketchy, but it handles the situation where there's no perfect solution allowing it to find an optimal solution instead. However I've not considered the case where the tree has two nodes or less (which is a kind of special case you would have to consider especially anyway).

Comment: The next step is that you know that the sum of cost in the resulting trees are about a third of the original. You then consider the subtrees of near that cost. After removing two such subtrees you will be left with the subtree containing the root also about the cost of one third.

Comment: I suppose you imagine a directed tree with specific root, as in computer science. However the problem seems to pertain undirected graph, that is a tree without a root specified. Wouldn't one need to run your algorithm N times then, starting it form each node as a root?

Comment: @CiaPan No I don't think so. For each undirected tree you can make it directed by simply selecting a root. After all the operation is just to remove two edges in both cases and the algorithm considers all edges.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem requires removing exactly two branches, so whichever node we select as a root, the solution (whether unique or not) is always effectively pruning two subtrees.